# Flash isn't rendering the model error during a save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't understand why my flash is not displaying when trying to save a model that contains validation errors.

My controller has this in the create method:

```
  if @post.save
    redirect_to admin_posts_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
```

My layout has the following:

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
<% end %>
```

Now if I add a puts statement to output the errors on the post model, I can see them in my logs.

```
if @post.save
  redirect_to admin_posts_path
else
  puts "model errors are: #{@post.errors.inspect}"
  render 'new'
end
```

> @messages={:title=>["can't be blank"], :body=>["can't be blank"]},
>   @details={:title=>[{:error=>:blank}], :body=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>

Why wouldn't the flash error be displaying when I try and save a post?
It is clearly not saving, and the errors collection is non-empty.

Doesn't the model's errors get added to the flash automatically?

Comment: You have to explicitly set flash messages `flash.now[:alert] = something` (for the current request) or `flash[:alert] = something` (if you do a redirect). I don't see where you are setting that.

Comment: you mean I have to do ```flash[:danger] = @post.errors``` ?

Comment: Where are you getting flash[:danger] from? I'm assuming in your application layout you have not set a condition for it.

Comment: @Blankman, you have to assign what you want to store on the flash hash. I'd recommend you to read the Flash official guides https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

Comment: follow up to @arieljuod post Rails 7 release. You'll need to add a `status: :ok` (or whatever status works for you) after `render :index` (or whatever action works for you). Got this answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71982008/8659405

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing model validations and the flash which are completely separate - or at least implying a connection which is not there.

The flash is just a simple session based mechanism for passing messages to subsequent requests. Nothing is added to the flash automatically in Rails*.

Model errors are created by the validations in the model and are not persistent between requests. Rather you just iterate through them in the view in response to a form submission.

```
<% if @model.errors.any? %>
<ul>
  <% @model.full_messages.each do |m| %>
    <%= content_tag :li, m %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

This is done in the same request. Which is why you don't redirect in Rails when the validations fail.

Comment: * this applies to vanilla rails. There are plenty of gems like responders that automatically add flash messages.